Dynamic Programming Table Extension Causes Incorrect Results for Subset Sum Partition Problem
I'm working on a dynamic programming problem related to counting the number of ways to partition an array into two subsets such that the absolute difference between their sums is equal to a given value d. My solution works perfectly when I limit the DP table to the target sum (i.e.dp[n+1][target+1] ,but it fails some test cases when I extend the DP table to compute up to the total sum of the array instead of just the target i.e dp[n+1][sum+1]
My understanding was that since I'm only interested in values up to target, computing extra values in the DP table for sums greater than target shouldn't affect the final answer. However, that doesn't seem to be the case.
When I compute only up to target, the solution works fine and gives correct results.
The failure occurs when the DP table is extended unnecessarily to compute sums beyond target. but  shouldn't it give correct answer since the target subproblem still lies in dp....
Shouldn't it be safe to compute extra values without affecting the correctness of the final result?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please describe the dynamic programming approach in a more detailed way; please provide an explanation of the state space.
